# Firemonkey e VCL - Cursor do Edit não aparece

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, pascal

Tenho um projeto em VCL, com um form principal em VCL e um botão que abre um form em FMX com um edit, porém ao dar foco no edit o ponteiro não aparece e nem pisca, o problema só acontece quando abro um form em fmx em um projeto em VCL.

Abrindo o form fmx:

```
if Form1 = nil then Form1 := TForm1.Create(self);
form1.show;
```

[image: Aplicação com ponteiro não aparecendo no edit]

Comment: mas se clicar na edit o cursor ja aparece?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema adicionando `application.run` no formshow do form.fmx, pois quando abrimos um form fmx vindo de um form vcl ele fica em segundo plano, ao dar run na aplicação ele identifica que o form está ativo, o ponteiro funcionou perfeitamente.